# Jquery back to top button jumps to top instead of scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was exercising in creating a simple Back-To-Top button that activates when scrolling the page after a certain amount. This is the **jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
        $('.back-to-top-button').fadeIn(200);
    } else {
        $('.back-to-top-button').fadeOut(200);
    }
});

});



/*Scroll Plugin*/
$('.back-to-top-button').click(function(event) { 
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

and this is how I placed it in the **HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="back-to-top-button" style="display: inline;">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up"></i>
        </a>
```

Problem is, it won't scroll up, instead it just jumps on top. I can't find any solution on the web, as it seems it does this only on my site, and everytime I try it on other websites it works.

Comment: I don't see where you are setting the offset variable?

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnmvf9r7/1/ You're right, it must only do this on your website. Can you show us more of your code?

Comment: _“Problem is, it won't scroll up, instead it just jumps on top”_ – that likely means, that your click handler for the element does not get executed at all – either because the selector used to bind the event handler doesn’t match anything, or perhaps because a previous script error prevents further execution.

Comment: Sorry, little thing I forgot while copypasting - I declared
`var offset=250` before the `scroll` event. I'm executing also a plugin called jssocials, but the console doesn't show any particular error - should I place some `console.log` somewhere, if it helps?

Answer (score 0):

It now works. I've declared the `event handler` **inside** the `document ready` function

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var offset = 250;
var duration = 300;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
        $('.back-to-top-button').fadeIn(duration);
    } else {
        $('.back-to-top-button').fadeOut(duration);
    }
});


/*Scroll Plugin*/
$(".back-to-top-button").click(function(event) { 
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```